# Machined Aluminium Print Bed

Tags: heated-bed, bed-leveling

I'm currently printing on a glass bed and it is warped in the centre of the bed. Not by much, but enough that my prints aren't the quality I want them out. My work around at the moment is to print on a raft.

I'm thinking if I was to replace the glass bed with a aluminium bed. I know this has been asked before, but the difference is I can get the aluminium plate machined at 65 °C. By doing this will it remove the potential for a warp completely? Or will it still have the potential to warp even being machined at 65 °C?

Comment: What type of aluminum, cast or rolled? Is it heat treated? 5-, 6- or 7000 series? What is the thickness, 3 or 6 mm?

Comment: Sounds like you got a bad plate.  Try buying a replacement before getting too deep into "make a new one"